# In a DC motor, how is it that field flux can stay constant despite a changing load?

Tags: dc-motor, magnetic-flux

According to my research, field flux depends on motor current in a series configuration, and depends on armature voltage in shunt configuration. Since motor current and voltage change with varying loads, how is it that we can keep a constant field flux?

PS This is ignoring slight drops in field flux due to armature reaction.

Answer (score 3):

In the shunt configuration, the armature and field voltages are the voltage of the supply. If the supply voltage is held constant, then it does not change with varying load. If the supply voltage is not held constant, it will vary due only to the voltage drop across the internal resistance of the supply. If that resistance is small, as it should be, the voltage variation with load will be small. The voltage drop across the armature resistance will cause the back emf to change and the speed will change accordingly, but the field voltage will be unaffected.

In the series configuration, the armature current also flows in the field, so the field flux changes as the load varies and can not be kept constant.

If the field is provided by a permanent magnet or separate power supply, the armature voltage can be changed without affecting the field flux. The field supply voltage can be changed to change the field flux without affecting the armature voltage.

Comment: Does this change between paralell, series or separate magnitizing winding configuration?

Comment: @winny See additions to answer.

Comment: Very useful information for anyones future search in the issue!

Answer (score 0):

In fact it doesn't stay constant with DC machines you have listed. The only machine that has a constant filed is permanent magnet DC machine, and the DC machine with separate excitation. Latter if fed with constant excitation current has the constant excitation field: \$ \Psi_{exc} \propto I_{exc} \$. But usually these machines are also fed with constant excitation voltage and the flux is slightly changing, because  the resitance of the winding is changing over temperature, as said this change is very small.
All other type of motors: shunt, series, compound,...can be calculated from DC machine with separate excitation, the only difference is that field current is variable, related to armature voltage, current.